# My application on Glassfish 3.1 won't perform client authentication

Tags: http, ssl, glassfish, authentication

I have application consuming a SOAP service that uses transport-level authentication. We are trying to move the application from Tomcat to Glassfish 3.1. Unfortunately, Glassfish seems reticent to perform the client authentication needed by the SOAP service. The SSL stacktrace results in the message "uknown_ca".

I have my Glassfish server configured to use a keystore that contains each of the three entrust certificates in the auth chain (stored as -trustcacerts) as well as having imported the SOAP destination server's certificate too.

I have tried several from-scratch rebuilds of my Glassfish server and even resorted to trying the tomcat server's keystore file with no luck.

Does anyone know what is going on, or else how do I get Glassfish to provide me more useful information regarding the handshake and keystores involved (beyond the -Djava.net.ssl.debug flag).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A co-worker of mine came up with the solution. Points to Andrew.

The destination turned out to be sending us the `unknown_ca` message, as it did not understand the CA of the key that Glassfish was sending during the authentication process.

Removing the JVM argument `-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as` resolves the issue. One may also change the argument to specify the alias of the preferred key instead of letting the JVM determine the key to use.

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP server certificate should be imported into Glassfish's truststore, not keystore.

Comment: I've tried that, and unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: So the SOAP server's certificate's CA certificates should be imported into Glassfish's truststore with -trustcacerts.

Comment: I did that as well. I'm specifying the truststore and keystore via the server's config JVM arguments, am I safe to assume this is the correct place?

Comment: No. These are specified in the admin interface somewhere.

Comment: EJP, thanks so much for your help with this one. A co-worker of mine figured it out (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537976/my-application-on-glassfish-3-1-wont-perform-client-authentication/6598887#6598887 for more details).