# Java Jersey SSL client from Glassfish 3.12

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, certificate, jersey

I have written a Jersey REST web service, deployed on Glassfish and secured using a CLIENT-CERT realm. Now I would like to call it from an application deployed on the same Glassfish server (or possibly another).

I can successfully call the service over SSL from a standalone Java class. However when I call it from code deployed on the same server I get a null certificate chain error, i.e. the client does not supply a certificate when requested to do so by the server.

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: null cert chain`

If I use the Glassfish keystore and truststore with the standalone class by setting

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\cacerts.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\keystore.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
```

then it still works, but not from within Glassfish itself.

Comment: I found the answer on SO :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537976/my-application-on-glassfish-3-1-wont-perform-client-authentication