# Invoking https web services from Glassfish 4 returns HTTPS 403 Error

Tags: web-services, netbeans, glassfish

I am developing a web service client with NetBeans 7.4 in Glassfish 4.0; The host server runs https (secured). I could access the WSDL in NetBeans successfully and generated the required classes. The problem is that I get a error:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 403: Forbidden
```

when I deploy my application into Glassfish 4.0. Interestingly, this problem does not occur when I deploy into Tomcat or when I develop, build and run as a Java Desktop application.

Is there some setup I need to do on Glassfish? I noticed the host server I am accessing uses a Verisign Certificate.
Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after searching everywhere for a solution; I got the hint from [My application on Glassfish 3.1 won't perform client authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537976/my-application-on-glassfish-3-1-wont-perform-client-authentication) by removing         -Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as from the default glassfish domain's jvm option

Thanks!