# Java web service client issue (Axis Error-(403)Forbidden )

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, webservice-client

I'm trying to access a web service developed by another company using https. I wrote a java client but when I run it I get the following error:

> Anybody who encountered such problem? Need a huge help!

```
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (403)403 
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
  {}:return code:  403
&lt;!doctype html&gt;&lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot;&gt;&lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;HTTP Status [403] вЂ“ [Forbidden]&lt;/title&gt;&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;h1&gt;HTTP Status [403] вЂ“ [Forbidden]&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;hr class=&quot;line&quot; /&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Type&lt;/b&gt; Status Report&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Description&lt;/b&gt; The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;hr class=&quot;line&quot; /&gt;&lt;h3&gt;Apache Tomcat/8.5.15&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;
  {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:403

(403)403 
  at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
  at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
  at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
  at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
  at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
  at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
  at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
  at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
  at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
  at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
  at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
  at globus.IssuingWS.IssuingSoapBindingStub.listCustomers(IssuingSoapBindingStub.java:2517)
  at globus.IssuingWS.IssuingPortProxy.listCustomers(IssuingPortProxy.java:143)
  at com.is.tieto_globuz.tieto.TclientService.getTclientsFl(TclientService.java:365)
  at com.is.tieto_globuz.tieto.PagingListModel.getPageData(PagingListModel.java:59)
  at com.is.utils.AbstractPagingListModel.<init>(AbstractPagingListModel.java:38)
  at com.is.tieto_globuz.tieto.PagingListModel.<init>(PagingListModel.java:31)
  at com.is.tieto_globuz.customer.AddCstViewCtrl.onClick$btn_fill_globuz(AddCstViewCtrl.java:2229)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.GenericEventListener.onEvent(GenericEventListener.java:81)
  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(EventProcessor.java:192)
  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:138)
  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.sendEvent(Events.java:306)
  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.sendEvent(Events.java:329)
  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent$ForwardListener.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:3052)
  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process0(EventProcessor.java:192)
  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:138)
  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1626)
  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1410)
  at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1134)
  at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:562)
  at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:457)
  at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:465)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is very similar to the ones described below:

[My application on Glassfish 3.1 won't perform client authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537976/my-application-on-glassfish-3-1-wont-perform-client-authentication)

[Invoking https web services from Glassfish 4 returns HTTPS 403 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442889/invoking-https-web-services-from-glassfish-4-returns-https-403-error)

Comment: Unfortunately, above links are of different cases. Additionally, no asnwers are provided which at least I could have got some idea how to fix(